# Pontuação em frases militares

Tags: pontuação

Estou em dúvidas sobre como pontuar corretamente uma frase, normalmente de cunho militar:

> Pode me ouvir, câmbio?

É perceptível que é uma sentença interrogativa, pois alguém está perguntando se o interlocutor consegue lhe ouvir, porém o jargão militar em si, **câmbio**, de certa forma pode dar a entender que a sentença é afirmativa.

Como eu fiz está correto ou eu deveria quebrar em dois segmentos:

> Pode me ouvir? Câmbio!

Comment: Eu acho que a segunda é a mais apropriada, pois é perguntado se o ouvinte pode ouvir e depois dito "câmbio". Já a primeira parece que o locutor está falando *com* o câmbio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neste caso, pode ser que a resposta esteja no entendimento do dispositivo de comunicação e na função da palavra **câmbio**.

A comunicação por rádio é do tipo **half-duplex**, ou seja, ambos dispositivos podem transmitir e receber dados, **porém não simultaneamente**, a transmissão tem sentido bidirecional, mas somente um dispositivo pode transmitir por vez. Nesse tipo de comunicação a palavra **câmbio**, que aparece no final da fala, indica que conclui a fala e estou passando a palavra ao interlocutor. Isso se repete durante todo o diálogo.

Portanto, a pontuação mais adequada será a do segundo exemplo:

> Pode me ouvir? Câmbio!

A frase é interrogativa e a palavra **câmbio** vem em outro segmento, ou seja, deixei de falar para ouvir. O ponto de exclamação também é válido, pois existe enfase na palavra.

Referências:
**Duplex**. Disponível em: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex. Acesso em: 12 jul. 2016.
**O que significa a palavra "câmbio" nas comunicações via rádio?**. Disponível em: https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080722180526AAv7kDL. Acesso em: 12 jul. 2016.

Comment: Beleza, então ;)

Comment: Será que o mesmo seria válido para frases não militares? como por exemplo: `João?! Venha aqui agora!`, ao invés de `João, venha aqui agora!`?

Answer (score 0):

> Pode-me ouvir? Câmbio!

seria o correto pelas razões que o @Denis Caixeta mencionou (faltava apenas o hífen).

Em português de Portugal o mais correto seria:

> Consegue ouvir-me? Cambio!

Comment: "Pode-me ouvir" talvez seja o correto de acordo com a  norma, mas a sensibilidade dos falantes repele essa construção, pois a questão é se o outro está me ouvindo, não se ele está me podendo...

Comment: Certo, fica estranho o verbo "poder" aplicado aqui: "Pode-me ouvir? Não, não posso, estou muito ocupado". Daí preferir o verbo "conseguir": "Consegue ouvir-me? Sim, consigo ouvi-lo perfeitamente."